# IntelliJ: Git Push Messed Everything Up

Tags: git, intellij-idea, push, commit

I've been working really hard on a personal project all day, and finally got around to wrapping things up and doing a commit and push. I clicked "Commit" in IntelliJ, and while the prompt for commiting would show up, it wouldn't respond when I clicked on it. Okay, just my luck, I thought. Something's gone wrong and I'm going to lose all of my progress. I didn't panic. I clicked "Commit and Push" and all seemed just fine, until I got an error message about a merge with the main branch not working on Git. What? I didn't ask for a merge! Lo and behold, for some reason it absolutely messed up all of my code and I have no idea why.

All over my files, there's things like
"<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HEAD"
">>>>>>>>>>>> ORIGIN"
all over the place, and all of the code from my last commit
is scattered all throughout my new code. Now I'm having to stay up late and manually go through and erase all of these bizarre lines that have seriously messed everything up.

Am I the only one to ever have a random and super frustating thing like that to happen in IntelliJ?

Comment: looks like intellij accidentally merged the diff text with the code, happened to me once but i wasnt using intellij

Comment: I don't know what IntelliJ itself did here, but a Git push never does that. A Git `pull` might, because pull means *run `fetch`, then run a second command* and the second command can involve merges, and those kinds of things come from merges. But `push` never merges.

Comment: I got really pissed off and made a whole post on it here just out of dire frustration. I started going through manually fixing things and accidentally messing other things up like the dufus that I am. IntelliJ allows you to roll back entire directories to prior saves. Luckily, I'd been saving things as I was going, lol. My heart is still beating with the frustration. About to try pushing to Git again. Wish me luck!

Comment: For some reason, the IDE hangs when I try to commit and push like I normally would. Very strange. I've got everything squared back to the way it was before the mess started. I ended up force pushing which worked just fine.

Comment: If the push was rejected, IntelliJ might have asked you to do a merge or rebase (or automatically did it depending on your config) and then you have conflicts to resolve. But you have to resolve them using the "nice" IntelliJ diff window, not going in the text files manually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using the `git revert` command to go earlier position wrong before the push was made. (HEAD position can be seen using `git reflog`). Then, you can try sorting the program using `git pull` and rebase it with your origin.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem easy enough just by using the option to revert to a prior save included in IntelliJ (which I didn't know about until after I posted the question), but I'll keep a note of your answer in case I ever run into this kind of problem in a non-IDE environment. I'm still very new to programming, and git has consistently been very daunting and confusing to me.